# In Ansible, how can I show the variable name in a debug module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Say I have a defaults/main.yml file that has

```
---
var1: my_value1
var2: my_value2
```

Now I want to print my vars in a debug

```
---
- debug: ??? what to put here ???
  with_items:
  - "{{ var1 }}"
  - "{{ var2 }}"
```

So I show

```
The value of var1 is my_value1
The value of var2 is my_value2
```

var and msg only show the value, not the variable name? This seems so simple but I can't find in in the Ansible docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. It's not quite the message I wanted, but it at least shows me the item name and its value

```
- debug: var="{{item}}"
  with_items:
  - var1
  - var2
```

and I get

```
TASK [python3 : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=var1) => {
    "item": "var1",
    "var1": "my_value1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=var2) => {
    "var2": "my_value2",
    "item": "var2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with_dict` to show var names but you have to define your variables differently :

```
---
vars:
 var1: 
   my_value1
 var2: 
   my_value2
```

And then you can do :

```
---
debug: 
 msg: "The value of {{item.key}} is {{item.value}}"
with_dict: "{{ vars }}"
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use a dictionary, that is, use the code as is?